# How to transpose only 2 columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I currently have the table like this

[image]

I want it changed to  :

[image]

I tried using df.melt(['genre'], var_name='Date', value_name='Value') but it's not giving the correct answer.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.genre,df.year,df.pop_median,aggfunc=lambda x : x)` or pivot table, you can also look into unstack

Comment: I think here is necessary use `pivot`